# ListView issue in QML

Tags: qt, drop-down-menu, navigation, qt-creator, qml

I'm trying to develop an application which has multi-layered navigation in drop-downs.
Below is the snapshot of the requirement. On clicking QSR only the subitems of QSR should pop out with proper alignment.

[image: original requirement]

But with my implementation, I'm getting following result. The pop out window is not aligned, but extending itself to the list.

[image: my implementation]

Below is the my code snippet

```
import QtQuick 1.1

Item {
    width: 500
    height: 300

    ListView {
        anchors.fill: parent
        model: nestedModel
        delegate: categoryDelegate
    }

    ListModel {
        id: nestedModel
        ListElement {
            categoryName: "QSR"
            collapsed: true

            subItems: [
                ListElement { itemName: "KFC" },
                ListElement { itemName: "Mc Donalds" },
                ListElement { itemName: "Pizza Hut" },
                ListElement { itemName: "Brain's" }
            ]
        }

        ListElement {
            categoryName: "Drinks"
            collapsed: true
            subItems: [
                ListElement { itemName: "Pepsi" },
                ListElement { itemName: "Coke" },
                ListElement { itemName: "7up" },
                ListElement { itemName: "Bacardi" }
            ]
        }
    }

    Component {
        id: categoryDelegate
        Column {
            width: 200

            Rectangle {
                id: categoryItem
                border.color: "black"
                border.width: 5
                color: "white"
                height: 50
                width: 200
                anchors.left: parent.right

                Text {
                    anchors.right: parent.right
                    x: 15
                    font.pixelSize: 24
                    text: categoryName
                }

                MouseArea {
                    anchors.fill: parent
                    onClicked: nestedModel.setProperty(index, "collapsed", !collapsed)
                }

            }


            Loader {
                id: subItemLoader
                visible: !collapsed
                property variant subItemModel : subItems
                sourceComponent: collapsed ? null : subItemColumnDelegate
                onStatusChanged: if (status == Loader.Ready) item.model = subItemModel
            }
        }

    }

    Component {
        id: subItemColumnDelegate
        Column {
            property alias model : subItemRepeater.model
            width: 200
            Repeater {
                id: subItemRepeater
                delegate: Rectangle {
                    color: "#cccccc"
                    height: 40
                    width: 200
                    border.color: "black"
                    border.width: 2

                    Text {
                        anchors.verticalCenter: parent.verticalCenter
                        x: 30
                        font.pixelSize: 18
                        text: itemName
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Any help to achieve original requirement will be appreciable.

Answer (score 1):

Have a close look at the delegate for your main list view: It's `Column` (put items on top of each over) of the main menu item and `Loader` for the popup menu. Obviously as soon as you load a popup menu it's displayed under its corresponding menu item in the list.

To get the behavior you intended you have to move the `Loader` for the popup menu out of the `ListView`:

```
import QtQuick 1.1

Item {
    width: 400
    height: 300

    Row {
        anchors.fill: parent

        Loader {
            id: subItemLoader
            width: 200
            height: parent.height
            property variant subItemModel: null
            sourceComponent: subItemModel == null? null: subItemColumnDelegate
            function setModel() {
                if (status == Loader.Ready) item.model = subItemModel
            }
            onStatusChanged: setModel()
            onSubItemModelChanged: setModel()
        }

        ListView {
            width: 200
            height: parent.height
            model: nestedModel
            delegate: categoryDelegate
        }
    }


    ListModel {
        id: nestedModel
        ListElement {
            categoryName: "QSR"

            subItems: [
                ListElement { itemName: "KFC" },
                ListElement { itemName: "Mc Donalds" },
                ListElement { itemName: "Pizza Hut" },
                ListElement { itemName: "Brain's" }
            ]
        }

        ListElement {
            categoryName: "Drinks"
            subItems: [
                ListElement { itemName: "Pepsi" },
                ListElement { itemName: "Coke" },
                ListElement { itemName: "7up" },
                ListElement { itemName: "Bacardi" }
            ]
        }
    }

    Component {
        id: categoryDelegate

        Rectangle {
            id: categoryItem
            border.color: "black"
            border.width: 5
            color: "white"
            height: 50
            width: 200

            Text {
                anchors.centerIn: parent
                x: 15
                font.pixelSize: 24
                text: categoryName
            }

            MouseArea {
                anchors.fill: parent
                onClicked: {
                    if (subItemLoader.subItemModel != subItems)
                        subItemLoader.subItemModel = subItems
                    else
                        subItemLoader.subItemModel = null
                }
            }
        }

    }

    Component {
        id: subItemColumnDelegate
        Column {
            property alias model : subItemRepeater.model
            width: 200
            height: 500
            Repeater {
                id: subItemRepeater
                delegate: Rectangle {
                    color: "#cccccc"
                    height: 40
                    width: 200
                    border.color: "black"
                    border.width: 2

                    Text {
                        anchors.verticalCenter: parent.verticalCenter
                        x: 30
                        font.pixelSize: 18
                        text: itemName
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

}
```